# Can MFC library view show in UWP 2015?

Tags: mfc, clr, wrapper, uwp

I'm trying to create MFC CView from UWP. But I don't know how to do it. Can anyone help me. :(. I did it from WPF or Window Application Form, and it works well.

Comment: What issue did you encounter? Could you be more precise?

Comment: I made a solution which connect a WPF project with CLR (Class Library Runtime) project. And I created successfully a CView attached to my WPF form. But in UWP, I can't do it.
I have library of MFC, and want to use it in C#. So I must do that.

Answer (score 0):

No. We cannot use MFC code in UWP app. WPF and Winform application are both classic win32 app. But UWP runs in a sandbox and only support a subset of win32 apis.

So we have to re-implement it in UWP.

Comment: Here are some links can help you start https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn996906.aspx , https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh699871.aspx and https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/mt186162.aspx

Comment: Above links are for C++ developers. But if you want to try convert the logic from your previous MFC code, I don't think it's an easy work. Consider implement it in c# if you are more good at it. Enjoy. :)